# R: setting environment names as arguments to new.env()

Tags: r, environment-variables

Is there a way to initialize the three names "indian", "pizza", and "ramen" as arguments when calling new.env()?

```
eats <- new.env(
    indian = "8elements",
    pizza = "blue line",
    ramen = "orenchi")
```

This would be an alternative to:

```
eats <- new.env()
eats$indian = "8elements"
eats$pizza = "blue line"
eats$ramen = "orenchi"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some alternatives:

**1)** Create a list and convert it to an environment

```
eats <- list2env(list(
    indian = "8elements",
    pizza = "blue line",
    ramen = "orenchi"))
```

**2)** Another possibility is to use `local` like this:

```
eats <- local({ 
  indian = "8elements"
  pizza = "blue line"
  ramen = "orenchi"
  environment()
})
```

**3)** The proto package creates proto objects which are actually environments so:

```
library(proto)
eats <- proto(
  indian = "8elements",
  pizza = "blue line",
  ramen = "orenchi")
```